# Implementing paging, sorting and filtering functionality in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sorting, pagination, filtering

I'm trying to develop a small project. I have a View on which I need to implement paging, searching and sorting functionality. My model is:

```
public class LicensesListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<License> Licenses { get; set; }
    public PageInfo PageInfo { get; set; }
    public SearchModel SearchModel { get; set; }
    public List<SortInfo> SortInfoList { get; set; }
}
```

Where PageInfo:

```
public class PageInfo
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalItems { get; set; }

    public int TotalPages
    {
        get { return (int) Math.Ceiling((double) TotalItems / ItemsPerPage); }
    }
}
```

SearchModel:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public string Other { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DtFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DtTo { get; set; }

    public string SelectedDep { get; set; }
    public SelectList DropDownDepartment { get; set; }

    public string SelectedIts { get; set; }
    public SelectList DropDownIts { get; set; }
}
```

And SortInfo:

```
public class SortInfo
{
    public string SortColumn { get; set; }
    public string SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

So, paging works good, but when I try to implement searching and sorting it brokes. Here is my Controller List action method:

```
        public ViewResult List(SearchModel search, List<SortInfo> sortInfo, int page = 1)
    {
        if (search != null)
        {
            SearchModel sm = Session["Search"] as SearchModel;
            if (sm != null) // needed because dropdowns set to null?
            {
                search.DropDownDepartment = sm.DropDownDepartment;
                search.DropDownIts = sm.DropDownIts;
                Session["Search"] = search;
            }
            else Session["Search"] = search;
        }
        else search = Session["Search"] as SearchModel;

        LicensesListViewModel model = new LicensesListViewModel();
        model.Licenses = Repository.Licenses.Items;

        /*Get search condition*/
        Func<License, bool> predicate = GetFilter(search);
        if (predicate != null)
        {
            model.Licenses = model.Licenses.Where(predicate);
        }
        model.SearchModel = GetSearchModel(search);

        /*Get sorting condition*/
        if (sortInfo == null)
        {
            sortInfo = new List<SortInfo> {new SortInfo {SortColumn = "Id", SortOrder = "DESC"}};
        }
        else if (sortInfo.Count < 1)
        {
            sortInfo.Add(new SortInfo {SortColumn = "Id", SortOrder = "DESC"});
        }
        model.SortInfoList = sortInfo;
        foreach (SortInfo si in sortInfo)
        {
            switch(si.SortColumn)
            {
                case "Id":
                    model.Licenses = GetOrderBy(si.SortOrder, model.Licenses, license => license.Id);
                    break;
                case "CodeLic":
                    model.Licenses = GetOrderBy(si.SortOrder, model.Licenses, license => license.CodeLic);
                    break;
                case "CodeAct":
                    model.Licenses = GetOrderBy(si.SortOrder, model.Licenses, license => license.CodeAct);
                    break;
                case "ItsId":
                    model.Licenses = GetOrderBy(si.SortOrder, model.Licenses, license => license.ItsId);
                    break;
                case "Pib":
                    model.Licenses = GetOrderBy(si.SortOrder, model.Licenses, license => license.Pib);
                    break;
                case "DepartmentId":
                    model.Licenses = GetOrderBy(si.SortOrder, model.Licenses, license => license.DepartmentId);
                    break;
            }
        }

        model.Licenses = model.Licenses
                              .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                              .Take(PageSize);

        /*Get paging*/
        model.PageInfo = new PageInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = predicate == null
                                 ? Repository.Licenses.Items.Count()
                                 : Repository.Licenses.Items.Where(predicate).Count()
            };

        return View(model);
    }
```

SearchModel is shown in partial view on modal window on the same page as list:

```
@model LicenseManager.WebUI.Models.LicensesListViewModel
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("SearchView", Model.SearchModel);
} 
<div class="table-responsive">
</div>
<!-- Page numeration -->
@if (Model.PageInfo.TotalPages > 1)
{
<div class="text-center">
        <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
            @Html.PageLinks(Model.PageInfo, i => Url.Action("List", new { page = i, search = Model.SearchModel}))
        </ul>
    </div>
}
<!-- Rows count -->
<div class="text-right">
    <span class="label label-default">Rows: @Model.PageInfo.TotalItems</span>
</div>
```

There are few troubles:

1. When I try to do first search submit it works fine, but when I go to next page search parameter is setting to null. ViewBag is also sets to null I've tried it. As you see I decided to use Session["Search"], but I don't think it is a good decision for such problem. Can you help me to take better variant? Or how can I do this with AJAX? Is it a good choice?
2. The second problem is how would I pass the List to List action? Where I can fill it up with column names and their sort order. Or at least for only one column sorting capability?
3. How to configure my routing?

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot pass collections or models containing properties that are complex objects or collections to a GET method using `Url.Action()`

Comment: Depending on the scenario, you might be able to load everything onto the client and make client-side paging/sorting with some simple JavaScript.Here is a small JS Fiddle I found [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LiquidSky/djav37tg/) that shows a possible solution. If you have 100.000 records with 10 records per page, this is not the go to solution at all... But if you have 50 records with 10 record per page, you should consider it to improve user experience as well.

Comment: Hm..I will have near 1000 records in future, but I'd like to make more elegant solution, which will suitable and for 100000 records)